# angular event bind can I create own attribute in HTML and send it to the class file

Tags: angular

```
 <div>
        <input type="text" value="myInputText"  (click)=onAddCart($event)>
        <button (click)=onAddCart($event) value="car" myvalue="bike">Car</button>
    </div>



     onAddCart(event:any){
        console.log(event.target.myvalue);
        }
```

Questions

1. I am getting undefined
2. Can I create the own attribute in HTML and send it class file
3. is it a good practice of angular

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you explain more about getting undefined? Maybe you could make a small working example on https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3fla9s . You can use your own event attributes in form of any data type that you wish, examples: `<button (click)=onAddCart(“Mercedes”) value="car" myvalue="bike">Car</button>`

Answer (score 0):

from your code nothing is clear and can you please be more specific about the requirment ,it seems you are trying to achieve event emit using output() but code and question is not complete